# CSS to png generator

Tags: css, png

I love all of the gnarly CSS3 background things that people are doing. But what I want to do is this:

1: Design a cool background using CSS3.
2: Export it to png/gif so that you can use it with all browsers.
3: Set up a cool script which converts the CSS3 to pngs automagically for older browsers.

Ok, so I've been researching this, and there seems to be a plurality of tools which convert png to CSS3, but none which do the reverse. Basically, I'm looking for the logical inverse of this:

http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2011/04/25/css-3-gradients/

Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to implement your own css 'engine' in order to do stuff like that. A good starting point would be to draw the css effects on a canvas, which could then be easily exported to png or any other format.

Comment: check out http://code.google.com/p/image2css/ it seems to do the trick - good ol' google! you may also like http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter/Create

Comment: No, he wants it the other way css2image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use PhantomJS: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture

```
phantomjs rasterize.js gradient.html gradient.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really a generator, but you could do this:

1. Download and install latest Firefox
2. Install Firefox plugin called Abduction - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/abduction/?src=api
3. Design your background using CSS3
4. Load that background in Firefox
5. Right click your page, select "Save Page as Image"
6. Save your image as PNG